# What does "separate kitchen" mean in apartments in London?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental

I am looking for a studio with private kitchen/bathroom. I see a plethora of properties that mention:

> SEPARATE KITCHEN

what does that mean?

A separate room, that has a private to you kitchen, or a shared kitchen with others leaving on the same floor?

Comment: I am leaning to the first alternative (ie opposite of an open-plan kitchen). Though with a significant number of real estate adverts being mis-represented, I guess the best way to proceed is to send a message to ask. (Can't substantiate, thus only a comment).

Comment: To be clear, I meant the adverts are mis-representing (or equivalently, the real estates are being mis-represented).

Comment: If cooking is at all important get specifics on the appliances. In looking for information on this I found a "kitchen" that was a corner big enough for one person to stand, with room only for a very small refrigerator etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the kitchen is not in the same room as the open-plan bedroom/living room.  If the kitchen was shared, the property would be described as a "room" (or "en-suite room" if there was a private bathroom), rather than an a studio apartment (also know as "studio flat").

As mentioned in the comments, estate agents' descriptions can be ... imaginative.  There may not be an actual door between the kitchen and the bed (although there should be).  If this is important to you, ring or email and ask.